How do I calculate the instantaneous rate of heat lost from this enclosure with a 18W heater inside that is controlled by an on-off programme?
How do I calculate the instantaneous rate of heat lost from this enclosure?
The junction box, shown in Figure 1 below, has dimensions of 155 mm * 092 mm * 210 mm, with a wall thickness of 2.6 mm.
I wanted to keep its internal temperature at an average of 18 °C, so I used a heat pad (12 V DC at 1.5 A) to provide 18 W of heat, controlled using an ON-OFF control system. The upper and lower temperature limits were set to 19 °C and 17 °C, respectively.
I measured the internal temperature of the junction box over a period of 6 hours and 22 minutes. For the vast majority of the system's operation, it was in a room at a temperature between 12.0 °C and 13.3 °C. I have this data in a table below.
I have a graph displaying the enclosure's internal temperature with respect to time below - see the third figure. I also have the raw data containing all temperature measurements.
How can I determine the instantaneous rate of heat from the enclosure given this data?
Explanation of the regions presented in the graph:
Region A:
This region presents the temperature measured while the system was located in the hot environment, which was at approximately 30 ℃.
Region B:
This region shows the decrease in the enclosure’s interior temperature as the system was moved from the hot environment to its testing environment.
Region C:
This region presents a period of stability for the system. The enclosure’s interior temperature began to drop immediately after it left the hot environment. Once this temperature dropped below the lower limit, the heat pad turned on and the interior temperature was increased until it reached the upper limit. Once the upper temperature limit was reached, the system turned the heat pad off. The temperature again dropped until the lower temperature limit was reached, and this cycle repeated itself.
The average period for the cycles in this region was 14 minutes and 48 seconds.
The average temperature in this region was 18.0014 ℃. From this, it can be taken that the system worked as required to maintain an average temperature of approximately 18 ℃ during normal operation in an environment which was colder than the system’s setpoint.
Region D:
Region D began when the system’s switch was turned off in order to observe its behaviour. With the switch turned off, the system stopped providing power to the heat pad and the indicator LED. The enclosure’s interior temperature was allowed to drop to approximately room temperature.
Region E:
When the enclosure’s interior temperature reached approximately room temperature, the switch was turned on again and the system provided power to the heat pad and the indicator LED.
The system brought the enclosure’s interior temperature back to the upper limit, at which point a new cycle of oscillating between the two temperature limits began. In this period of stability, the average temperature inside the enclosure was 17.9458 ℃.
The switch was turned off during the final rise of the interior’s temperature at 06:54.




What's the accuracy of the temperature sensors used? must have been really expensive to get 5 digit accuracy...

The number of decimal places is based on averaging the temperature readings in a given region. It's a Texas Instruments LM35.  I can acknowledge the number of decimal places is excessive, I just wanted to show that I had not calculated a perfect average of 18 °C.

the table does not match the graph

As far as I can tell from your graph, the heater is on half the time during each cycle of its normal operation.  This means it’s supplying an average of 9W. That’s the heat loss from your box.
For a more accurate figure simply attach a timer that counts whenever the heater is on. Run the box for a time T, find out from the timer how long the heater was operating (t) and there you have it. Average power is simply $18\frac{t}{T}$
Heat transfer through conduction is proportional to the temperature difference, so there is no problem using average values.
For your figures, average internal temperature was 18C, average environmental temperature was approx 12.8C. This means you were transferring heat at $18\frac{t}{T\ (18-12.8)} \frac{watts}{C}$.
For instantaneous heat transfer rates just multiply this by the temperature difference between the box and its environment.
Here's an approximate graph of your instantaneous heat transfer rates:


Admirable work, but you may be overdoing it. I would:

Switch the heater on at 100% duty cycle (provided it doesn't overheat the box) and allow the inside temperature to stabilise1. You are now losing 18 W through the box.
Measure the internal and external temperatures, $ T_i %$and $ T_o $.
Calculate $\Delta T = T_i - T_o $.
The setup is analogous to Ohm's law, $ V = IR $. In your case $\Delta T = PR$ where $P$ is the heater power (18 W) and $R$ is the thermal resistance of the case. Rearranging we get
$$ R = \frac {\Delta T}P \ \text{°C/W}$$.

An example:

$P$ = 18 W.
$T_i$ = 33°C.
$T_o$ = 21°C.
Thermal resistance = $ \frac{33 - 21}{18}  = 0.67\ \text{°C/W} $

With that information you should be able to calculate the heat loss for any power / temperature combination as well as calculating the maximum temperature rise inside the enclosure.

Note that this sort of calculation is very common for semiconductor heatsink calculations so you should find plenty of articles on the topic. Heatsinks are also rated in °C/W.

1 If that makes the box too hot then reduce it to 50% duty cycle and assume 9 W heat loss.
